# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError even though java -version and javac -version are the same

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi, ubuntu-18.04, openjdk-11

In my university we are learning about writing RMI applications. When I first tried running the example application in Eclipse 2019-03 I ran into the error:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError
I successfully ran other projects (non RMI) without any problems.

When I run

```
java -version
```

I get:

```
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, mixed       mode, sharing)
```

and

```
javac -version
```

I get:

```
javac 11.0.3
```

I have Java 8 and 11 installed on my system running Ubuntu 18.04. 
When looking for a solution to the problem, I found this question:
[How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi/16345710)

Changing the settings of the compiler compliace level in Eclipse to 1.8 did AND changing the project specific Settings helped me and I was able to finally run the Application without any errors. This solution does not satisfy me though.

When I run

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

and

```
update-alternatives --config javac
```

in both cases openjdk11 is selected.
I do not understand, why I get the error if i dont change the compiler settings.

One of the answers suggested it is a wrongly set $JAVA_HOME varable. When I run:

```
jrunscript -e 'java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"));'
```

It indeed gives me the answer

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

I tried following this guide to change it to openjdk11:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java
When I now run

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I get:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

but when I run

```
jrunscript -e 'java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"));'
```

again the answer is still the same.

I want to be able to use my openjdk 11 to compile and run the code without changing the compiler settings in Eclipse. Anybody had the same problem and a tip for me?
Thank you in advance!

The full error is the following:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: chapter6/Counter has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Comment: Eclipse has an internal setting that determines which JRE/JDK is used. Check if it's on JRE 11 or 8.

Answer (score 1):

The /etc/alternatives is ignored when running inside Eclipse. Instead, you have a separate definition of which JDK/JRE to use. This can be set globally in the Eclipse Preferences, one-by-one in the Project Properties, or even at the Debug/Run configuration (in order to test your application in multiple java versions).